# Match GET_URI if URL don't use symbols only letters and numbers

Tags: php

Im trying to get the URL of the page what the visitor access example page:
https://example.com/sitemap-index.xml

But i want to check ( for protection ) if /sitemap-(A1).xml
A1 - Is only letters or numbers

Example of good URLs

https://example.com/sitemap-index.xml

https://example.com/sitemap-1.xml

https://example.com/sitemap-2.xml

Example of bad URLs

https://example.com/sitemap-ind-ex.xml

I try using this PHP command

```
 $GET_URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 if(preg_match('/\/sitemap-[^A-Za-z0-9].xml/', $GET_URI)) {
  $Page_Type = 'Sitemap';
 }
```

How i can fix this, so i can match the good pages?

Answer (score 0):

After checking what im doing wrong ... i success to fix it this way

```
 if(preg_match('/\/sitemap-([A-Za-z0-9]+).xml/', $GET_URI)) {

 }
```

If someone needs ...